# 2 customer created with master slave configured

Tags: mysql, database, magento, master-slave

With master slave configured on magento 1.4.1.

When I place order from backend two customers are created. One customer
is with all the information added during order and one user without
firstname, lastname and other information.

Comment: I added an error_log in Mysql.php in function query. I see following query and I think this is why it is created twice ====[Fri Nov 26 10:01:00 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] INSERT INTO `customer_entity` (`email`, `group_id`, `store_id`, `website_id`, `entity_type_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)==== [Fri Nov 26 10:01:01 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] INSERT INTO `customer_entity` (`store_id`, `group_id`, `entity_type_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `website_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: If you disable `default_read` in your config so it goes back to a single server database does it definitely work normally again?

Comment: See the commented line of this code http://pastebin.com/Q73mcSH5 . This is the place duplicate customer was getting created. After commenting this it doesn't create duplicate customer when master slave is on OR off. Need to investigate why this was called and why it was creating.

Comment: As per Boris reply on google group "Yeah I can see why it happens.

The write (master) and read (slave) are separated DBs

So, when you just created a customer it exists only on master, but not on slave, so when you try to read it doesn't find one:
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($address->getCustomerId());

Now, you try to save it without ID or any data, so it creates a new one.

Nice find."

Comment: How do I resolve this. How do I tell magento to read customer form master and not from slave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to fix this

Changed

```
class Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Customer extends
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Initiate resources
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $this->setType('customer');
        $this->setConnection(
            $resource->getConnection('customer_read'),
            $resource->getConnection('customer_write')
        );
    }
```

to

```
class Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Customer extends
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Initiate resources
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $this->setType('customer');
        $this->setConnection(
            $resource->getConnection('core_setup'),
            $resource->getConnection('core_setup')
        );
    }
```

Let me know if there is any other way to solve this.

Comment: Before you were writing to `customer_write` and reading from `customer_read` - two different servers. By changing to `core_setup` you are both writing to and reading from the same server, the master, which solves the problem. I suppose you could also use `customer_write` for both but that still means reading from the master for all customer records which doesn't sound efficient.

Comment: Yes, right, even I think its not efficient. I am looking for better solution.

Comment: Also I am facing same problem when I save Role. When I save role all users under that role disappears :)

Comment: Have you considered a master-master setup instead?

Comment: No, I didn't tried that. I don't know how master-master setup can solve this problem, can you explain.